# Making phone call in Australian app ios

Tags: ios, xamarin, tel

I am currently running into an issue with Xamarin Studio and making phone calls.

I am having an issue when trying to make a call to an Australian phone number from an app that is only available in the Australian app store.  I am using

```
  UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(new NSUrl(tel:{phoneNumber}))
```

but it is showing that there is nothing found that can handle the phone number.  The number is in a format such as: XXXXXXXXXX.  I looked over Apple's documentation about Phone links, but it only shows how to setup the format for phone numbers located in the US.  I am located in the US and published the app under their account.  Do I need to include the country code? or is there something else that I am missing entirely?

I know the above code is deprecated in iOS10.  I am mainly concerned with why the number is not working.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: are you testing with a device that is set to use the Australian locale?

Comment: There is nothing specific about Australian numbers in terms of the tel URL. All a tel URL does is pass the series of digits to the phone application which then attempts to place the call. If the URL contains “*” or “#” then the URL is ignored for security reasons but the URL is not otherwise validated. The first thing I would do is split the line in two. Confirm that you are getting a non-nil URL. Also, is this you actual code? As the string isn’t quoted.

Answer (score 0):

You can include the country code *(+61 for Australia country code)* in the phone number directly like below:

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(new NSUrl("tel:" + "+61123456789"));
```

From your example:

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(new NSUrl(tel:{phoneNumber}));
```

I assume that your phoneNumber is a parameter.

So maybe you should use:

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(new NSUrl("tel:" + phoneNumber));
```

[This](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/86047ecea5c2b1463e7f783ca3b80d030644d39b/Phoneword/Phoneword/Phoneword.iOS/PhoneDialer.cs) is a Xamarin Phone call example.